# Custom UITableViewCell class in Xcode 4.2

Tags: ios, uitableview

I've been following [this Apple Doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7) to add a custom UITableViewCell that I layed out in an .xib to my project.  One problem with the doc is that it seems like it was written for an older version of Xcode.

I'm able to load my UITableViewController that the custom cells are on, but the cells are all blank.  My custom cell contains several UILabels, and has a non-default background color.  The table that appears when I run has the default white background and no labels.  If I change the UITableView's View -> Background on my storyboard, the color of the cells' background changes, but the labels still don't appear.

Of interest is the fact that the data is still in my table's cells.  The UITableViewController is itself called as a popover from another controller.  When I select one of the cells, the strings from the various `label.text`s are supposed to be loaded into their own labels on the popover's delegate, and that code works fine (except when I try to include a UINavigationBar in my popover, but that's probably another issue entirely).

I'm still pretty new to iOS developement, so if there's anything I'm leaving out or being unclear about let me know.

Edit - cleaned up code, now is completely different question than when I originally posted, but is still on the same topic.  Should I have deleted the old question and posted this as a new question all together, or is it alright that I just edited it?

Comment: I was looking closer at this, and it looks like I mixed some code from some other techniques...I'm going to clean my code up a little and that may end up fixing my issue, or I may edit my question if there are still any issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still not entirely sure what was wrong with what I was doing before, but I managed to get what I wanted.  I originally dropped a UITableViewController onto my storyboard set up a popover segue (also on the storyboard) and tried to display the popover with `performSegueWithIdentifier`.  Instead, I now create the popover completely in my code (which I found a nice tutorial for here on SO, by goggling "show popover programmaticly"), without having anything for it on my storyboard.  That seems to be the most documented and stable way to show a popover.  Once I displayed it that way, my custom cells showed up exactly like I wanted.